# Find $r$ such that the equation $x^4+x^2(1-2r)-2x+1=0$ has only one real solution

Tags: roots

I'm looking for $r$ such that the equation $$x^4+x^2(1-2r)-2x+1=0$$
has only one real solution. I've made some attempts to this problem, but it seems that I even didn't get close to the solution. The approximation for $r$ is 0.3347498 
Is it possible to find analytic solution for $r$ and if yes then how?
Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Because this is a quartic and the complex roots come in conjugate pairs, the only chance is a double root. A double root of $f(x)$ is a root of the greatest common factor of $f(x)$ and its derivative $f'(x)$. What did checking that give you?

Comment: You could say that since $r = \frac{x^4 + x^2 - 2x + 1}{2x^2}$, if you graph the right hand side as a function of $x$ the problem is asking what values in the range are achieved exactly once.

Comment: Mathematica gave
$$r=\frac{3}{8}+\frac{1}{8 \sqrt{\frac{3}{67+\sqrt[3]{791776-27168 \sqrt{849}}+2\ 2^{2/3}
   \sqrt[3]{24743+849 \sqrt{849}}}}}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{67}{24}-\frac{1}{48}
   \sqrt[3]{791776-27168 \sqrt{849}}-\frac{1}{12} \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(24743+849
   \sqrt{849}\right)}+\frac{255}{8} \sqrt{\frac{3}{67+\sqrt[3]{791776-27168 \sqrt{849}}+2\
   2^{2/3} \sqrt[3]{24743+849 \sqrt{849}}}}}$$ for the key root of the resulting quartic. Don't know if simplification/denesting is possible :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has noted, the polynomial should have a real double root and two conjugate complex roots, so its general form is
$$
(x-a)^2[(x+p)^2+q^2]
$$
Expanding this, and comparing with our initial polynomial we have the relations
\begin{alignat}{2}
&-&&a^2 p^2-a^2 q^2+1=0,\\
&-&&2 a^2 p+2 a p^2+2 a q^2-2=0,\\
&-&&a^2+4 a p-p^2-q^2-2 r+1=0,\\
&&&2 a-2 p=0
\end{alignat}
From forth equation we have $p=a$, so the system reduce to
\begin{alignat}{2}
&-&&a^4-a^2 q^2+1=0,\\
&&&2 a q^2-2=0,\\
&&&2 a^2-q^2-2 r+1=0
\end{alignat}
From the second we have $q^2=1/a>0$
so the system reduces to
\begin{alignat}{2}
&-&&a^4-a+1=0,\\
&&&2 a^2-\frac{1}{a}-2 r+1=0
\end{alignat}
So the problem is reduced to look for a positive solution to
$$
-a^4-a+1=0
$$
and once found, we have, from the second
$$
r=\frac{2 a^3+a-1}{2 a}
$$
The only positive solution for $a$ is
$$
a=0.7244919590005157
$$
so that
$$
r=0.3347498141075979.
$$

Answer (score 1):

We can write the function in following form where $c>0$.

$(x-a)^2((x-b)^2+c)=0$

$(x^2-2ax+a^2)(x^2-2bx+b^2+c)=0$

$x^4-(2a+2b)x^3+(a^2+b^2+4ab+c)x^2-(2ab^2+2ac+2a^2b)x+a^2b^2+a^2c=0$

Therefore,

$b=-a, c={1-a^4\over a^2} > 0$

$2ab^2+2ac+2a^2b=2a^3+{2-2a^4\over a}-2a^3=-2,a^4-a-1=0$

$1-2r=a^2+b^2+4ab+c=2a^2-4a^2+{1-a^4\over a^2}={1-3a^4\over a^2}=-{3a+2\over a^2}$

$r={a^2+3a+2\over 2a^2}$

We take the real root where $a^4<1$ in $a^4-a-1=0$ which is around $-0.72449$ and gives $r$ around $0.33476$. And yes, there is a closed formula for quartic equation using radicals so $r$ also has an exact formula as well, but it should be pretty messy.

Answer (score 0):

Equation $$x^4 + x^2 (1 - 2 r) - 2 x + 1 = 0$$
has only one real solution if the curve $y=x^4 + x^2 (1 - 2 r) - 2 x + 1$ is tangent to $x$-axis, that is: the curve has a absolute minimum, provided that $y''=2 (1-2 r)+12 x^2$ is positive, which means $1-2r>0\to r<\frac{1}{2}$

Derivative is $y'=4 x^3 +2 (1-2 r) x-2$. We have $y'=0$ for $r=\frac{2 x^3+x-1}{2 x}$.

Substitute in the given equation
$$x^4 + x^2 \left(1 - 2\cdot \frac{2 x^3+x-1}{2 x}\right) - 2 x + 1 = 0$$
which gives
$$x^4+x-1=0$$
Real solutions are
$$x_1=-1.22074;\;x_2= 0.724492$$
Correspondent $r$ values are
$$r_1=2.3998;\; r_2=0.33475$$
$r_1$ must be discarded because it is larger than $1/2$ so the unique solution is
$$r = 0.33475$$